# Unable to generate UUID id for my entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm working on a web project using:

- Spring 4.x (Spring Boot 1.3.3)
- Hibernate 4.x
- PostgreSQL 9.x

I'm new to Postgres DB and for my tables I decided to use (for the first time) `UUID` identifiers, but I'm having some troubles...

For ID field I used Postgres `uuid` type and I set as default value `uuid_generate_v4()`. All works correctly when I generate a new row directly by a PSQL insert, but I cannot create a new record by my application.

As an example, this is how I declared an entity in my application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    // other fields and methods...

}
```

For this declaration I'm using the `Type` Hibernate annotation.

*Find* operations work well, but when I try to make an *insert* I get this exception:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): net.myapp.User;

Followiong [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers) I tried to solve the issue. I changed my entity definition to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    // other fields and methods...
}
```

But now I'm getting wrong ID values when I retrieve (existing) data from DB (still haven't tried insert...).

So what is the right way to define ID field in my case?

---

**UPDATE**

Using the second definition...

When I try to find by ID, I'm getting:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = bytea
>     Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

When I try to create new record:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];

Comment: Did you try to add just `@Id @GeneratedValue` without the `Column` and `GenericGenerator`?

Comment: @AliDehghani thank you I'll take a try

Comment: yes, working with uuid in postgres through ORM always was a pain in a .. head. i've spent a few days with this problem two years ago. a few tips: 1. you need uuid enabled in postgresql (just ensure you can generate them from console) 2. uuid - bytea error means that your insert was incorrect and it saved id as bytes 3. to exclude generator problems first try to create them in java: id = UUID.randomUUID();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following configuration and it works. I am using Glassfish as application server.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@Column(name = "key", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Type(type="pg-uuid")
private UUID key;
```

The table key has the Postgres `uuid` type:

```
CREATE TABLE billuser.billingresult (key uuid NOT NULL,   .... )...
```

Answer (score 9):

I used this configuration and this is working for me and 
I am using

- Spring Boot 1.5.2
- Hibernate 5
- PostgreSQL 9.6

Entity.java

```
@Id  
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;
```

before that I am suggesting you to load `uuid-ossp` it into your database to use it.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the "uuid-ossp"?

Comment: uuid-ossp is postgress module which provides some reusable functions for UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Worked as a charm:

- Create a custom configuration class

  ```
  package mypackage;

  public class PostgresUuidDialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {

  @Override
  public void contributeTypes(final TypeContributions typeContributions, final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
      super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
      typeContributions.contributeType(new InternalPostgresUUIDType());
  }

  protected static class InternalPostgresUUIDType extends PostgresUUIDType {

          @Override
          protected boolean registerUnderJavaType() {
              return true;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- In your *application.properties* add this

*spring.jpa.database-platform=mypackage.PostgresUuidDialect*

(change *mypackage* according to your needs)

Pros: you don't need to use any special annotation in your JPA entity

Cons: this *obscure* class in your project...